# How to use file in Python script?

Tags: python, python-2.6

I'm working on a Python script and can't seem to figure out the last part of it.  Here's the code:

```
def aggregate(data):
    data.sort()
    i = 0
    while i < len(data) - 1:
        while i < len(data) - 1 and data[i][1] >= data[i+1][0]:
            data[i] = (data[i][0], max(data[i][1], data[i+1][1]))
            data.pop(i+1)
        i += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    itervals = [(1,4), (2,2222), (2,3), (4,7), (8,15), (16,31), (32,63), (64,127), (128,255), (256,511), (512,1023), (1024,2047), (2048,4095), (4096,8191), (8192,16383), (16384,32767), (32768,65535), (65536,131071), (131072,262143), (262144,524287), (524288,1048575), (1048576,2097151), (2097152,4194303), (4194304,8388607), (8388608,16777215)]


    formatted = lambda vals: '[{0}]'.format(', '.join('({0}-{1})'.format(
                                                   iterval[0], iterval[1])
                                                   for iterval in sorted(vals)))


    print(formatted(itervals))
    aggregate(itervals)
    print(formatted(itervals))
```

Right now I'm being forced to manually enter in ranges of numbers, as you can see on this line:

```
itervals = [(1,4), (2,2222), (2,3), (4,7), (8,15), (16,31), (32,63), (64,127), (128,255), (256,511), (512,1023), (1024,2047), (2048,4095), (4096,8191), (8192,16383), (16384,32767), (32768,65535), (65536,131071), (131072,262143), (262144,524287), (524288,1048575), (1048576,2097151), (2097152,4194303), (4194304,8388607), (8388608,16777215)]
```

Instead, I want to open the file `intervals.txt` and use the content from it, which is this:

```
1,4
2,2222
2,3
4,7
8,15
16,31
32,63
64,127
128,255
256,511
512,1023
1024,2047
2048,4095
4096,8191
8192,16383
16384,32767
32768,65535
65536,131071
131072,262143
262144,524287
524288,1048575
1048576,2097151
2097152,4194303
4194304,8388607
8388608,16777215
```

How do I open the `intervals.txt` file and use its content instead?  There aren't any parentheses in it, so I wasn't sure if that would be an issue.  Also, the ranges are broken up by line breaks instead of commas (as you can see above).

In response to @sideffect, this is what's being output by your code:

```
[(1-4
), (1024-2047
), (1048576-2097151
), (128-255
), (131072-262143
), (16-31
), (16384-32767
), (2-2222
), (2-3
), (2048-4095
), (2097152-4194303
), (256-511
), (262144-524287
), (32-63
), (32768-65535
), (4-7
), (4096-8191
), (4194304-8388607
), (512-1023
), (524288-1048575
), (64-127
), (65536-131071
), (8-15
), (8192-16383
), (8388608-16777215)]
[(8388608-16777215), (1-8388607
)]
```

This is what should be output:

```
[(1-4), (2-3), (2-2222), (4-7), (8-15), (16-31), (32-63), (64-127), (128-255), (256-511), (512-1023), (1024-2047), (2048-4095), (4096-8191), (8192-16383), (16384-32767), (32768-65535), (65536-131071), (131072-262143), (262144-524287), (524288-1048575), (1048576-2097151), (2097152-4194303), (4194304-8388607), (8388608-16777215)]
[(1-4095), (4096-8191), (8192-16383), (16384-32767), (32768-65535), (65536-131071), (131072-262143), (262144-524287), (524288-1048575), (1048576-2097151), (2097152-4194303), (4194304-8388607), (8388608-16777215)]
```

Comment: You need to look at a tutorial on string splitting and basic Python IO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this will be a better solution for your requirement

```
data = [line.strip() for line in open("sample.txt", 'r')]
splits=[line.split(",") for line in data]
x=[int(i[0]) for i in splits]
y=[int(i[1]) for i in splits]
final=[tuple([i,j]) for i,j in zip(x,y)]
print final
```

and you will get a result like this:

```
[(1, 4), (2, 2222), (2, 3), (4, 7), (8, 15), (16, 31), (32, 63), (64, 127), (128, 255), (256, 511), (512, 1023), (1024, 2047), (2048, 4095), (4096, 8191), (8192, 16383), (16384, 32767), (32768, 65535), (65536, 131071), (131072, 262143), (262144, 524287), (524288, 1048575), (1048576, 2097151), (2097152, 4194303), (4194304, 8388607), (8388608, 16777215)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) for getting an idea about opening files

**Q1: How do I open the intervals.txt file and use its content instead ?**

```
itervals = []
# you can use `open` function to read from file 
with open("intervals.txt") as f:
     for line in f:
         # read line by line & append to make the list
         # NOTE: a space is also read in line, try strip function to remove it
         # to lazy check, uncomment below code, it will print length of line string
         # print len(line)
         itervals.append(line.split(','))
```

**Q2.There aren't any parentheses in it, that an issue ?**

No, python will not read text file as its data structures, by paranthesis you mean tuples, its your script that needs to be modified for further data transformation, in the above code i hope you got an idea of reading a file line by line, from there you can use the available python functions to process the string to your needed format

Comment: Isn't this editing the text received from `intervals.txt` and making it become `1,4, 2,2222, 2,3` when it should be `(1,4), (2,2222), (2,3)` ?  I got an error when running it on Python 2.6.  Could you post a full copy of the code that's working for you?

Comment: Just added an explanation at the end of my original post.  Basically it looks like it's being caused by how your code is either adding or interpreting line breaks?

Comment: Added more details in answers, I hope SO is created for clarifying doubts not getting all problem logic code, check the links & answer details for solving the problem @Andrew